# Problems with Atari Punk Console circuit

Tags: 555, speakers

I am trying to build an APC using the following schematic:

[image: APC Schematic]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FYN/A0QM/GM7E8XNX/FYNA0QMGM7E8XNX.MEDIUM.jpg))</sub>

And the output is having some issues.

Sound only comes out when the rightmost potentiometer is at 0 resistance, and in that position the rightmost 555 heats up rapidly. In any other spot, the speaker simply makes clicking noises.

One possible difference is that I am using TLC555 chips instead of LM555 as suggested in the diagram. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a TLC555 should not be a problem. The behaviour you observe is a failing of the APC circuit itself.

When the rightmost potentiometer is at 0 resistance, the 555 heats up rapidly because, internally, pin 7 shorts to ground during parts of the oscillation, to discharge the 0.1uF capacitor. With the potentiometer at 0 ohms, this results in a direct short across the power rails and a very large current flowing through pin 7 (as well as a direct short discharging the capacitor). The absolute maximum current through pin 7 for the TLC555 is 150mA. To ensure this isn't exceeded, you could try connecting 220 ohm resistors (I'm assuming a 9V supply) in series with both potentiometers, and also between pins 6 and 7 of the rightmost 555.

Most of the audio range of the circuit is contained within the lowest 20% or so of the resistance of the right-most potentiometer. Try reducing the value of this potentiometer, or connecting a 10k 'fine tuning' potentiometer in series with it, if you want more precise control.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and replaced the 500k potentiometer with a 50k one, but audio was still only heard at the lowest 5% of the potentiometer, and dropped down quickly when slightly higher than 0 resistance. In addition, when held one of these low resistances, the 50k potentiometer began to burn up. It seems like this circuit is supposed to have a greater diversity in range of the second potentiometer than it does, but for some reason this potentiometer doesn't seem to be contributing much to audio.

Comment: Sounds like something else might be wrong too then; try connecting the output to pin 3 of just the left 555. You should get a tone which can be varied over a large pitch range. Try setting this to a high squeek, then reconnecting the right 555. Its possible that your right 555 has been damaged by excess current, though they are typically pretty robust.

Comment: I think I must have put the capacitor in the wrong spot or some other wiring problem, because I rewired the second 555 according to the diagram and it worked fine. Thank you for all of your help though.

Comment: An interesting answer. How did you come up with a value of 220 Ω? Was this just a random low value that you chose? For a 9V supply I calculate that only 60 Ω is required: R=V/I=9/0.15=60. Also, would a minimal resistance be required for the astable (the first 555), as there is already a 1KΩ resistance between 7 and GND (although I guess as 7 goes to ground during the low of the oscillation, then, at that point, there would be a need)? Thirdly, wouldn't the resistor between pins 6 and 7 on the monostable (the second 555) affect its operation (as, by design, they are meant to be shorted)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I even burnt the 555 of the right on your figure.
I was using a 8 ohms speaker. Then I added 100 ohm resistors in serie at the exit of the 555 to limit the output current just before the connection with my speaker and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I put together this exact circuit some time ago and it works perfectly for me. Here's a tutorial and demo video I made with background information on the circuit design, details on the construction process, and several demos.

[Atari Punk Console | Tutorial and Demo](http://youtu.be/LbVDpv5OEf4)